# PHP file upload missing tmp_name

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I downloaded and installed xampp for windows. When i try to upload pictures, video or music to my localhost in php i just get $_FILE['some_file'][name] i dont get [size], [type], [error] and most important to my [tmp_name]. But when i try to upload some .rar file or some document i get all these file informations. Here is what i get when i try to upload some music files:

```
    Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Blondee – Moment (Original Mix) www.livingelectro.com.mp3
            [1] => Eli & Fur – Turn The Lights Down www.livingelectro.com.mp3
            [2] => Fake Forward Ft. CHRYSTAL - Brush It Off (Club Mix) www.livingelectro.com.mp3
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
        )

)
```

[type] and [tmp_name] is empty and [error] shows errors and [size] shows 0kb.

But when i try to upload some rar files everithing is working:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Aaargh.zip
            [1] => afta-sans.zip
            [2] => armata.zip
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => application/octet-stream
            [1] => application/octet-stream
            [2] => application/octet-stream
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\php95EE.tmp
            [1] => C:\xampp\tmp\php95FF.tmp
            [2] => C:\xampp\tmp\php9600.tmp
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13835
            [1] => 32570
            [2] => 26454
        )

)
```

Here is my index code:

```
<?php
    $files = $_FILES["postFile"];
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($files);
    echo '</pre></br></br>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you notice in the ones where you do not get all the array occurances filled you do get all the uploaded files flagged with errors!

```
[error] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
    )

1 = UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
```

That will be why none of the other fields contain what you expect.

You must always check the error array before doing anything with the uploaded files.

You need to check the `php.ini` file for this parameter and probably increase the max size.

```
upload_max_filesize = ?
```

And quite possibly this one too.

```
post_max_size = ?
```

The `post_max_size` will need to be large enough to cope with the `upload_max_filesize * number of files uploaded` + a few k to cope with other fields passed at the same time and general overhead.

......

Comment: yes, but i need to get [tmp_name] and this field is blank

Comment: Its BLANK because NO FILE WAS ACTUALLY UPLOADED due to them being to large.

Comment: upload_max_file_size was 8mb and i changed it to 200mb